# What are XML Plugins for Intellij IDEA similar to XML Tools for Notepad++?

Tags: xml, intellij-idea

Currently, we have XMLTools plugin for Notepad++ which basically does some kind of prettifying the XML within Notepad++.

Do we have a similar plugin for Intellij, which does the prettifying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has built-in functionality for XML reformatting (Code | Reformat Code). You can configure formatting options in Settings | Editor | Code Style | XML.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ supports reformatting XML out of the box without the need for plugins.

From the official help at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/reformatting-source-code.html#d1711579e29 :

> Reformatting code for the current file
>
> To reformat code for the current file, follow these steps:
>
> In the editor of the currently opened file, press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+L. 
>   Note that if you select Code | Reformat Code from the main menu or
>   press Ctrl+Alt+L, IntelliJ IDEA will try to reformat the source code
>   automatically without opening the Reformat File dialog. In the
>   Reformat File dialog, specify options for the reformatting and click
>   Run.